# Pulling down on the title bar does not resize window?

Tags: 14.04, titlebar, globalmenu

Previous versions of Ubuntu had a neat feature where I could drag down the title bar (on the global menu) of any window to resize it (to get a smaller window), but I see that this feature is lacking in Ubuntu 14.04. How can I fix this/get this back?

Comment: You can't do that when it is fully maximized, this will happen when the window has not occupied the complete screen.

Comment: That feature is still present in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @Sudheer is correct. Fully maximized windows will still exhibit the behavior you are asking about in 14.04 32 and 64 bit. Pushing a window to the top will maximize it and pulling it down has the effect of restoring it to it's previous unmaximized size

Comment: What is this feature called?  I need to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

In 14.04 as in Previous releases (back to 12.04 certainly) Pushing a window to the top will maximize it and pulling it down has the effect of restoring it to it's previous unmaximized size